# How to Join Column by Comma?

Tags: sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT CAST(Numero as varchar(255)) + ';' as Result  FROM Acao
```

This code returns this:

[image]

I want to return a single line like this: "52;56;57;59", because I want to put this in a formula of a computed column.
How do I do this using SQL?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SELECT 
    ( 
    STUFF 
    ( 
       ( 
       SELECT ';' + CAST(Numero AS varchar(255)) + CHAR(10) 
       FROM Acao 
       ORDER BY BE_ID 
       FOR XML PATH, TYPE 
       ).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
       , 1, 1, '' 
    ) 
    ) AS XmlDecodedStuffInsteadSubstring